# how to get link inside function() { ...}?

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I can't share full code now.

It's a portion of jquery code

```
$('#contentBox').hover(
                function() {
                    posi("5",768,"box.jpg","i need link here","some text here");
                }
```

I tried this

```
$('#contentBox').hover(
                function() {
                    posi("5",768,"box.jpg","<a href='#'>i need link here</a>","some text here");
                }
```

and this

```
$('#contentBox').hover(
                function() {
                    posi("5",768,"box.jpg","&lt;a href='#'&gt;i need link here&lt;/a&gt;","some text here");
                }
```

But both are not working.

How to get link working here?

I mean i want to render `i need link here` as `<a href='#'>i need link here</a>`

Comment: Would be helpful if you could share what posi() actually does :-)

Comment: I don*t understand a word. What do you mean "get link working"? What does posi() do?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to rewrite the posi function to use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

http://api.jquery.com/html/

But as long as you don't share your posi() function, this is just a guess.